# This code should use the links its scraped from scrapy to extract the second paragraph in the first div but I'm getting this error

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

```
exceptions.TypeError: Request url must be str or unicode, got list:
```

Above is the error I'm receving, is it my indentation?

And here is my code.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from bathUni.items import BathuniItem
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from urlparse import urljoin

class recursiveSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'recursive2'
    allowed_domains = ['http://www.bristol.ac.uk/']
    start_urls = ['http://www.bristol.ac.uk/international/countries/']

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        links = []

        for i in range(1, 154):
            xpath = ('//*[@id="all-countries"]/li[*]/ul/li[*]/a/@href' .format (i+1))
            link = hxs.select(xpath).extract()
            links.append(link)

        for link in links:
            yield Request(link, callback=self.parse_linkpage)

    def parse_linkpage(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = BathuniItem()
        item ['Qualification'] = hxs.select('//*[@id="uobcms-content"]/div/div/div[1]/p[2]').extract()

        yield item
```

How would I get this to work and follow the links from the first page to extract data from the links? Any examples would be great.

Comment: Please provide the full traceback

Comment: Which version of scrapy are you using? Also, could you give an example of the information you're trying to scrape from each country page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the `scrapy` API, `hxs.seletct(...).extract()` returns a list. So in your code, `links` is list of lists, hence the call to `Request(link,...)` fails because `link` should be a string or unicode.

If you are sure that you only want to process the first result from `extract()`, you can simply change the way you append to `links` like this:

```
links.append(link[0])
```

If you want to process all results from `extract()`, change the `append` to this:

```
links.extend(link)
```

Also, I am not sure why you are using `yield` in `parse_linkpage`. As there is no loop in that function, `yield` will behave more or less like `return` (and `return` would be more conventional and efficient). Note that `parse_linkpage` will also return a list (again the result from `extract()`).

Comment: After changing a couple of these things I'm now receiving this error:  Missing scheme in request url.

Comment: It gives this error on the scraped links, and I believe the fix would be to add http://bristol.ac.uk on to the scaped links but I have no idea how to as I can't see these links.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I now get an error: local variable link referenced before assignment

Comment: goto isedev chatroom... we can discuss better there.

Answer (score 0):

Having checked the starting URL and examined the HTML, the range loop is unnecessary. With a sufficiently qualified xpath query, it's possible to pull all of the relative URLs for each country in a single select statement.

To that effect I've cleaned up the `parse` function. All of the required country URLs are parsed, but I'm not quite sure which section of each country page needs to be scraped so the items are still empty.

```
class recursiveSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'recursive2'
    allowed_domains = ['bristol.ac.uk']
    start_urls = ['http://www.bristol.ac.uk/international/countries/']

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        links = hxs.select('//*[@id="all-countries"]/li/ul/li/a/@href').extract()
        abs_links = ['http://www.bristol.ac.uk' + x for x in links]

        for link in abs_links:
            yield Request(link, callback=self.parse_linkpage)
```